# Alternatives to FireWatir working with Firefox 4 or higher

Tags: firefox, watir, firewatir, firefox4, jssh

It seems, from what I read, that we will not have a JSSH for Firefox 4, and therefore no FireWatir.
I have several scripts that run well on FireWatir, and of course I would like to update my Firefox to v4.
I would hate to rewrite all my scripts in a different system, since it would take a lot of efforts.
I don't like the idea to switch to IE; the main reason is that I can set Firefox to save all files to a specific directory, while I cannot do the same with IE.
What is the solution to get all my FireWatir scripts to run with the minimum effort with Firefox 4?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use watir-webdriver gem, it drives Firefox.

https://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver (github)
https://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver (rubygems)
https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/downloads (installation)

Comment: Thanks Željko, this seems exactly what I need.
But, the instance of Firefox it opens seems to have "forgot" the proxy setting. As a result, it cannot work.
Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Check the watir-webdriver [FAQ](https://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver/wiki/FAQ), especially the last item.

Answer (score 2):

For users that need's to use JSSH in newer versions, you can download it from:
http://abstracta.com.uy/en/descargas-2.html

this version is implemented over MozRepl but simulates exactly JSSH Console
Source is over Assembla at https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/mozrepl-jssh